# How do I access an object method inside a List?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, loops, object

I am creating a website using jsp. I have a method that returns each row from a `JDBC` query as an object. Each object is added to a list and returned to the jsp file.

This is the method that returns the list of categories stored in a MySQL database:

```
public List<Object> getCategories() throws Exception{
    this.catList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    try{
        sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM crm_categories";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            cat = new Category();
            cat.setAttributes(rs.getInt("cat_id"), rs.getString("cat_name"));
            this.catList.add(cat);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return catList;
}
```

The `Category` object looks like this:

```
@WebServlet("/Category")
public class Category extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Category() {
        name        = null;
        id          = 0;
    }

    public void setAttributes(int id, String name){
        this.name       = name;
        this.id         = id;
    }

    public String[] getAttributes(){
        String[] attributes = {this.name, String.valueOf(this.id)};
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

I have attempted to iterate through the list of objects. It prints "test" to the browser 7 times which is the correct number of categories:

```
dbCon conn          = new dbCon();
List<Object> catList;

// get a list of all categories
catList = conn.getCategories();
for (Object o : catList){
    out.println("test");
}
```

How do I access each Categories `getAttributes` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `getCategories` method returns a `List<Object>`, when it would make more sense for it to return `List<Category>`:

```
public List<Object> getCategories() throws Exception{
    // Note: this is now a *local* variable. There was no need for it to be an
    // instance variable as far as I can see.
    // If you're using Java 7 or higher, you can use new ArrayList<>(); too.
    List<Category> catList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
for (Category category : conn.getCategories()) {
    out.println(Arrays.toString(category.getAttributes()));
}
```

Comment: This works thanks Jon. Also your note about the local variable - I thought I understood that all variables should be declared at the top of the class and given a default value in the constructor before being used in 1 or more methods? Are you saying that if a variable is only being used in one method than it should be declared inside that method?

Comment: @crm: Well unless you need the value to persist as part of the state of the object. You need to understand the different types of variables: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access methods of the `Category` type, you must have another declaration:

```
dbCon conn = new dbCon();
List<Category> catList = conn.getCategories();
for (Category cat : catList) {
    // here you can access "cat.getAttributes()"
}
```

Of course, this requires you to change the method `dbCon.getCategories()`:

```
public List<Category> getCategories() throws Exception{
    this.catList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    ...
    return catList;
}
```

As `catList` is obviously a field, this must be changed, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Category> getCategories() throws Exception{
    List<Category> tmp= new ArrayList<Category>();

    try{
        sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM crm_categories";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            cat = new Category();
            cat.setAttributes(rs.getInt("cat_id"), rs.getString("cat_name"));
            tmp.add(cat);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.catList = tmp;
    return tmp;
}
```

Right answer has been posted, but id like to point, that `you should not use class field` in this method. If you will launch this method in two threads at the same time, it will cause to double some DB entries (in some cases all entries will be doubled).

Use local field and if this method should modify class field, do so before returning result.

access object is of course

```
for (Category c: getCategories()) {
    c.getAttributes();
}
```